# Generate randoms in child process

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fork

In the following code i do a bunch of forks and each child generate a random value, but when i exec the code, randomvalue is the same  in all the childs. Why happen this and how can i solve it?

I want a different random value for each child.

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        ret = fork();
        if (ret == 0) {
            /* child process*/

                    read(descriptor_fitxer[i][0], missatge, 50);
                    randomvalue = rand() % 50;
                    printf("Random is %d",randomvalue)
                    exit(0);


            }else{
            /*dad process*/
             wait(&st);}
```

Output:

```
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
Random is 31
```

Comment: Call `srand()` once in each fork, with a different seed value for each. Otherwise `rand()` follows the same sequence every  time. It is often seeded from `time()` but with one second granularity, this might not produce a different seed for every thread.

Comment: `multithreading != multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where and how do you use srand();
Try modifying your child's code like this

```
            read(descriptor_fitxer[i][0], missatge, 50);
            srand(time(NULL)+i);
            randomvalue = rand() % 50;
            printf("Random is %d",randomvalue)
            exit(0);
```

Also be sure to do `#include <time.h>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to seed the pseudo-random number generator with `srand()`.
Add

```
srand((unsigned int)(time(0) + i*i));
```

before calling `rand()`.

Typically, you would call `srand()` only once to seed. But if you seed only once before the loop, then `rand()` will the same sequence of numbers (that's how rand is designed to work). So seeding in *each* process is necessary.

Calling `srand((unsigned int)(time(0)));` inside loop might still have the same problem as the loop could run quick enough to have same seed. So I used `i*i` in case that happens.